# Eclipse hangs on install new software

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I open install new software in Eclipse, it starts downloading various jar files such as: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo/compositeContent.jar or http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo/SR1/content.jar. This process seems to take forever and it also greatly slows down my internet connection and prevents me from either updating or installing new software. Does anyone know how to fix or diagnose this problem?

Comment: For some reason, running [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to attempt to diagnose the problem fixes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is silly, but I installed [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to diagnose the problem, but I found out the problem never occurs when Fiddler is running.